# How to take existing android/ios library and turn into cordova plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am working on a cordova project. Looking through cordova plugins I can see there is java code for android/ios to use some native features. Is it possible to take an exsiting libray such as https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage for example and turn it into a cordova plugin easily?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. U can integrate a existing libary as plugin in Cordova. and just need to write some native codes to adapte the libary to Plugin Interface.
There is document:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html